# Monadic Retry logic w/ F# and async?

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I've found this snippet:

http://fssnip.net/8o

But I'm working not only with retriable functions, but also with asynchronous such, and I was wondering how I make this type properly. I have a tiny piece of `retryAsync` monad that I'd like to use as a replacement for async computations, but that contains retry logic, and I'm wondering how I combine them?

```
type AsyncRetryBuilder(retries) =
  member x.Return a = a               // Enable 'return'
  member x.ReturnFrom a = x.Run a
  member x.Delay f = f                // Gets wrapped body and returns it (as it is)
                                       // so that the body is passed to 'Run'
  member x.Bind expr f = async {
    let! tmp = expr
    return tmp
    }
  member x.Zero = failwith "Zero"
  member x.Run (f : unit -> Async<_>) : _ =
    let rec loop = function
      | 0, Some(ex) -> raise ex
      | n, _        -> 
        try 
          async { let! v = f()
                  return v }
        with ex -> loop (n-1, Some(ex))
    loop(retries, None)

let asyncRetry = AsyncRetryBuilder(4)
```

Consuming code is like this:

```
module Queue =
  let desc (nm : NamespaceManager) name = asyncRetry {
    let! exists = Async.FromBeginEnd(name, nm.BeginQueueExists, nm.EndQueueExists)
    let beginCreate = nm.BeginCreateQueue : string * AsyncCallback * obj -> IAsyncResult
    return! if exists then Async.FromBeginEnd(name, nm.BeginGetQueue, nm.EndGetQueue)
            else Async.FromBeginEnd(name, beginCreate, nm.EndCreateQueue)
    }

  let recv (client : MessageReceiver) timeout =
    let bRecv = client.BeginReceive : TimeSpan * AsyncCallback * obj -> IAsyncResult
    asyncRetry { 
      let! res = Async.FromBeginEnd(timeout, bRecv, client.EndReceive)
      return res }
```

Error is:

> This expression was expected to have type `Async<'a>` but here has type 'b -> `Async<'c>`

Comment: Where is the error occurring (line)?

Comment: Regarding the specific error, your `Bind` should take arguments as a tuple (write `x.Bind(expr, f)` instead of `x.Bind expr f`). That's probably the cause. However, it also does not use `f` at all, which is highly suspicious (and your `Return` has a wrong type).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Bind` operation behaves like a normal `Bind` operation of `async`, so your code is mostly a re-implementation (or wrapper) over `async`. However, your `Return` does not have the right type (it should be `'T -> Async<'T>`) and your `Delay` is also different than normal `Delay` of `async`. In general, you should start with `Bind` and `Return` - using `Run` is a bit tricky, because `Run` is used to wrap the entire `foo { .. }` block and so it does not give you the usual nice composability.

The [F# specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.pdf) and a free [chapter 12](http://manning.com/petricek/SampleChapter12.pdf) from Real-World Functional Programming both show the usual types that you should follow when implementing these operations, so I won't repeat that here.

The main issue with your approach is that you're trying to retry the computation only in `Run`, but the retry builder that you're referring to attempts to retry each individual operation called using `let!`. Your approach may be sufficient, but if that's the case, you can just implement a function that tries to run normal `Async<'T>` and retries:

```
 let RetryRun count (work:Async<'T>) = async { 
   try 
     // Try to run the work
     return! work
   with e ->
     // Retry if the count is larger than 0, otherwise fail
     if count > 0 then return! RetryRun (count - 1) work
     else return raise e }
```

If you actually want to implement a computation builder that will implicitly try to retry every single asynchronous operation, then you can write something like the following (it is just a sketch, but it should point you in the right direction):

```
// We're working with normal Async<'T> and 
// attempt to retry it until it succeeds, so 
// the computation has type Async<'T>
type RetryAsyncBuilder() =
  member x.ReturnFrom(comp) = comp // Just return the computation
  member x.Return(v) = async { return v } // Return value inside async
  member x.Delay(f) = async { return! f() } // Wrap function inside async
  member x.Bind(work, f) =
    async { 
      try 
        // Try to call the input workflow
        let! v = work
        // If it succeeds, try to do the rest of the work
        return! f v
      with e ->
        // In case of exception, call Bind to try again
        return! x.Bind(work, f) }
```

Comment: Can I somehow wrap the Retry<'a> from the snippet with Async<'a>?